# PhantomJS scraping of website gets different results than loading in browser

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

If you load the following website in your browser, you get the "5 day rolling" option for polling results, as specified in the URL. However, if you load the same thing with PhantomJS, you get the "Overall" option. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

http://polling.reuters.com/#poll/TM651Y15_DS_13/filters/LIKELY:1/dates/20160918-20160922/type/day

```
var paths = ["tvc"];

var urls  =["http://polling.reuters.com/#poll/TM651Y15_DS_13/filters/LIKELY:1/dates/20160918-20160922/type/day"];

function handle_page(url, path){

    console.log(url);

    var webPage = require('webpage');
    var page = webPage.create();
    var fs = require('fs');

    page.open(url, function(){
        var content = page.content;
        fs.write(path, content,'w');
        next_page();
    });
}

function next_page(){

    if(urls.length == 0){
        console.log("exiting");
        phantom.exit(0);
    }

    var url = urls.shift();
    var path = "reuters_" + paths.shift() + ".html";

    handle_page(url,path);
}

next_page();
```

Comment: Opened the link from smartphone and got "overall" results. Probably, mobile browsers are served a lighter version of the page and PhantomJS is considered as such because of its default resolution of 400x300. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632049/phantomjs-queryselectorall-textcontent-returns-nothing/39634086#39634086

Comment: that solved it. thanks!